# GitBash / GitExtensions issue committing local changes

Tags: git-bash, git-commit, git-extensions, git-add, git-status

I am a get newbie.

I have completed development and ready to check in my files.  I thought I checked everything in, but when I look at my repo, I see a sub-directory was not checked in.  So I tried to force the `git add . -f` but I got this error:

```
`$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch and 'origin/develop' have diverged,
and have 1 and 5 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working tree clean`
```

what should I do?

I don't care about any differences in the repo i want to put my code in the repo as is (no concern for what is in the repo, my code should replace everything)

again, what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

The two (`git add -f .` and `git status` output) are unrelated.

First, don't forget to commit what you just added.

Then, to replace the remote history with your own, simply do

```
git push --force
```

As long as you are the only one working on that develop branch, that will be fine.

Comment: Thanks, my colleague ended up committing my changes for me via SourceTree.